# How to perform a multi-path data update on Firebase when data is changed from the Firebase Console?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, denormalization

I am currently working on an iOS app and I'm using Firebase to power it.

Since my app is still relatively small I'm using the database to often perform manual amends on the data. My users can submit places (that I display on a map) and I review entries manually to ensure the data is complete and correct.

I have recently started using GeoFire and thus had to start **denormalizing my data** for the coordinates (lat & lon) of each places.

As a result I have **coordinates at 2 locations in my database**

1. under **/places/place_key/**...
2. under **/geofire/place_key/**...

I'm currently looking for a way to **automatically update** the /geofire side of my database **when I update** the latitude or longitude of a places on the /places side of the database **directly from the Firebase Console**.

I'm looking for tips on how to do that. Could Firebase Functions help me for this?

Cheers,

Ed

Comment: Yes, with write events cloud functions could do this for you. You are telling me you review manually to ensure the data is complete and correct. You should add firebase realtime database rules to check if the data is complete and in the right format.

Comment: Hey @J. Doe thanks for your comment. The reason I need to validate the data manually for now is because my users are not required to give me the exact location of the place they add so sometimes I will not have the coordinates and will have to find them myself and add them to the database manually. Hence why I'm trying to only have to update them once and not several times since my DB is denormalized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone happens to look for an answer to this question in the future, I followed @J. Doe advice and used [Firebase Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/).

The setup is super simple, steps [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started).

Here is sample code that let's me update several endpoint of my database when one of my object is updated.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);


exports.placeDataUpdated = functions.database.ref('/places/{placeId}').onUpdate(event => {

    const place = event.data.val();
    const key = event.params.placeId;

    console.log("Updated place data for key: ", key);

    var dataToUpdate = {};

    dataToUpdate["places_summary/"+key+"/city"] = place.city;
    dataToUpdate["places_summary/"+key+"/country"] = place.country;
    dataToUpdate["places_summary/"+key+"/latitude"] = place.latitude;
    dataToUpdate["places_summary/"+key+"/longitude"] = place.longitude;
    dataToUpdate["places_summary/"+key+"/name"] = place.name;
    dataToUpdate["places_summary/"+key+"/numReviews"] = place.numReviews;
    dataToUpdate["places_summary/"+key+"/placeScore"] = place.placeScore;
    dataToUpdate["places_summary/"+key+"/products"] = place.products;
    dataToUpdate["places_summary/"+key+"/visible"] = place.onMap;
    dataToUpdate["places_GeoFire/"+key+"/l/0"] = place.latitude;
    dataToUpdate["places_GeoFire/"+key+"/l/1"] = place.longitude;

    return event.data.ref.parent.parent.update(dataToUpdate);

});
```

It's super convenient and took next to no time to setup.